# Regex to match paragraphs

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text:

```
Terms: 1 I've got the {name} and {term}
    So I would like to go
    But not return

Terms: 2 I've got the {name} and {term}
    So I would like to go
    But not return

Terms: 3 I've got the {name} and {term}
    So I would like to go
    But not return
```

I'd like to match each paragraph, defined as starting with `Terms:` and ending with `2 or more newlines`.

[The closest I can get appears to be](https://regexr.com/497f7):

```
/(terms:).*(\n)*/gim
```

How can I get each paragraph to be returned as a separate group?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: C# - though working in regexr.com is enough for now.

Comment: No. regexr does not support .NET regex syntax.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/uv9h6T/1

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work on regexr.com

Comment: @MattW Do not test .NET regexps at regexr.com, as **it does not support .NET regex syntax**.

Comment: I understand that, but it is close enough in most cases. The answers/comments here so far have not worked - the closest have returned duplicates of one group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?sim)^terms:.*?(?=(?:\r?\n){2,}|\z)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fsim%29%5Eterms%3A.*%3F%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%7B2%2C%7D%7C%5Cz%29&i=Terms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return%0D%0A%0D%0ATerms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return%0D%0A%0D%0ATerms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return)

**Details**

- `(?sim)` - enable `RegexOptions.Singleline`, `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` 
  and `Regex.Multiline` options
- `^` - start of a line
- `terms:`  - a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=(?:\r?\n){2,}|\z)` - a location followed with 2 or more line break (CRLF or LF) sequences or end of string.

**USAGE**

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?sim)^terms:.*?(?=(?:\r?\n){2,}|\z)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Or, split with 2 or more linebreaks with

```
(?:\r?\n){2,}
```

See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%7B2%2C%7D&i=Terms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return%0D%0A%0D%0ATerms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return%0D%0A%0D%0ATerms%3A%20I%27ve%20got%20the%20%7Bname%7D%20and%20%7Bterm%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20So%20I%20would%20like%20to%20go%0D%0A%20%20%20%20But%20not%20return). It just matches 2 or more repetitions of an optional CR and LF symbols.

**USAGE**

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"(?:\r?\n){2,}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like..

```
(terms:.*\n.*\n.*(\n|))
```

https://regex101.com/r/5Dzp1F/1/